# Bad performance of Chromium after compiling

Tags: windows, google-chrome, compilation, chromium

I want to compile Chromium for windows with different patches from different projects for myself (at least for today). I follow this official instruction:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md
All steps successfully passed, but i get awful low perfomance. In speeDOMeter benchmark (https://browserbench.org/Speedometer2.0/) my build get only 5 points, while official build get 116! This is commands for GIT what i use:

```
gclient
mkdir chromium && cd chromium
fetch --no-history chromium
cd src
gn gen --ide=vs out/Default "--args=target_cpu=\"x86\""
autoninja -C out/Default chrome -j 6
```

What i was try and this is not help:

1. Delete depot tools folder, and start over
2. Decrease -j from 10 to 8 and to 6
3. Delete argument --ide=vs
4. Fetch with history
5. Use command "gn gen" without --args part
6. Disable windows defender & firewall

Comment: Looks like you might have built debug version. You should build release version

Answer (score 1):

As Asesh correctly noted, the problem was in debug mode. But adding key "is_debug=false" to gn gen command is not enough. The best solution will be the adding "is_official_build=true" key. Here is description:

```
is_official_build
    Current value (from the default) = false
      From //build/config/BUILDCONFIG.gn:136

    Set to enable the official build level of optimization. This has nothing
    to do with branding, but enables an additional level of optimization above
    release (!is_debug). This might be better expressed as a tri-state
    (debug, release, official) but for historical reasons there are two
    separate flags.

    IMPORTANT NOTE: (!is_debug) is *not* sufficient to get satisfying
    performance. In particular, DCHECK()s are still enabled for release builds,
    which can halve overall performance, and do increase memory usage. Always
    set "is_official_build" to true for any build intended to ship to end-users.
```

Thanks Asesh for pointing me in the right direction.